# Запятая или точка с запятой? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, точка-с-запятой

Верны ли оба варианта? Какой лучше?

1. Пол-лета уже-с прошло-таки, и я, серый кот, по имени Лео, ничего никак ещё не сделал.
2. Пол-лета уже-с прошло-таки; и я, серый кот, по имени Лео, ничего никак ещё не сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написала так:
*Пол-лета уже прошло-таки, **и** я, серый кот по имени Лео, ничего никак ещё не сделал.*

• Думаю, что перед "и" лучше поставить запятую.

> Перед союзами ***и, да*** (в значении *и*) точка с запятой ставится в том случае, когда они соединяют два предложения, которые без них были бы разделены точкой:
> «Псы пуще захрипели, лошади понесли; **и** Егорушка, еле державшийся на передке, глядя на глаза и зубы собак, понимал, что, свались он, его моментально разнесут в клочья, но страха не чувствовал, а глядел так же злорадно, как Дениска, и жалел, что у него в руках нет кнута» (А. П. Чехов).

• А вот перед "по имени" запятая не нужна.
Примеры:
*В доме Андерсенов у мальчика был только один благодарный слушатель — **старый кот по имени Карл*** (К. Г. Паустовский. Сказочник);
*Вот, скажем, **этот кот по имени Панкрат** — будь он в десять раз больше, он бы меня съел, потому что сильно меня не любит* (Сергей Юрский. Петров день).

[Когда нужна точка с запятой?](https://russkiymir.ru/publications/313712/)

Answer (score 4):

*Пол-лета уже-с прошло-таки, **а я, серый кот по имени Лео, ничего пока ещё не сделал.***

Союз в ССП должен выражать определенные отношения между предложениями. Здесь скорее **противопоставление,** поэтому лучше подойдут противительные союзы А или НО.

Comment: *союзы А или НО* — интересная запись. Понимаю: *союзы А и НО, союз А или союз НО, союз А или НО*. А вашу не понимаю.

Comment: Вряд ли это правильно. Похожее: *имена Катя или Шарон; слова "кошка" или "собака"*. Это же неверно по грамматике.

Comment: У меня согласование по смыслу (по Розенталю).

Comment: Множественное число объединяет, а "или" разделяет — получается что-то непонятное. Согласование по смыслу касается общих слов "большинство", "половина", "часть" и т.п. Там вроде бы нет ничего подобного (с "или"). Согласование по смыслу — привычная для всех вещь, а у вас что-то новое, непонятное (новаторство).

Comment: Новаторство не обсуждаем, это не по теме.

Comment: Кстати, плюс. Мне нравится ваш вариант с "а". Реально хорошо получается. Только признайте, что "или" ошибочно, такого нет в правилах.

Comment: Мерси! Я так старалась... Очень, очень приятно-с